# jquery autocomplete - display results in a custom div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I'm looking for some help in customizing the dropdown that displays the results of autocomplete. I have the following html which I want to use to display the results. The idea is that the div below is hidden to begin with and as soon there is a match, I make the div visible and each matched results would be wrapped in the < li > tag below.

```
<div class="search_dropdown_wrapper" style="display:none;">
    <div id="search_arrow" class="dropdown_pointer search"></div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="/assets/2c42cdf.jpg"  />
            <h4>Tom Jerry</h4>
            <p>Cartoon Characters</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            ...
        </li>
        ...  
    </ul>
</div>
```

The portion of my autocomplete code which works to display the results is..

```
  $('#search_name').autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    ...
    ...
  })
  .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li></li>" )
      .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
      .append( "<a>" + item.name + "</a>" )
      .appendTo( ul );
  };
```

(FYI, the above thanks to [How to set-up jquery-ui autocomplete in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188157/how-to-set-up-jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-rails))

At the moment I only have the name (item.name) displaying in the dropdown. How can I get the html I want into the code above. The part where I'm confused is how to get the div around the ul item which is being passed into the function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use .parent() to get to the div around the ul: http://api.jquery.com/prev/

```
$(ul).parent()
```

Or, to grab the previous sibling: (as I somehow though you needed to do at first)
http://api.jquery.com/prev/

```
$(ul).prev()
```

If ul is already a jQuery object, then you can just do ul.parent() and ul.prev()

Alternatively, you can access the wrapper div directly:

```
$('.search_dropdown_wrapper')
```

I might suggest adding an ID to that wrapper and accessing it by ID, eg:

```
<div class="search_dropdown_wrapper" id="search_dropdown_wrapper">
...
</div>
```

Then in your script you can use `$('#search_dropdown_wrapper')` to access the div directly.

The direct access approach is safer.  If you ever change your markup, it will still access the correct div (theoretically.)

Comment: Thanks, I prefer the direct approach too. I can do something like  .appendTo($('#search_dropdown_wrapper ul')); which works and the <li> is inserted into the ul; but since the $('.search_dropdown_wrapper') is hidden by default, how and where do I insert the code to make it visible? Having a hard time with that.

Answer (score 0):

Each item it is response objects collection. If in your reply the object has a field of the email access will be item.email. It is insert your autocomplete object into custom div with custom li tag:

```
$("#search_name").autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  open: function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("widget")
      .appendTo(".search_dropdown_wrapper")
      .css("position", "static");
    } 
}).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
   var html, paragraph;
   html = '<h4><a>' + item.name + '</a></h4>';
   paragraph = '<p>Cartoon Characters</p>';
   html = html + paragraph;
   return $('<li>').append(html).appendTo(ul);
};
```