# In rails, is there any gem works like the auto complete function in twitter?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

When we press @ key in the text field, there will be a list of available option nearby the cursor, which is similar in twitter or stackoverflow. I've installed the auto_complete plugin from jquery ui, but I'm not sure whether it's available in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery autocomplete should work just fine.  You just need to give it a list to autocomplete from, or you can set it up to query the database over ajax for larger lists.

See a bit of a walkthrough here: [How to set-up jquery-ui autocomplete in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188157/how-to-set-up-jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-rails/3222639#3222639)

More info on an autocomplete gem here: https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete
And an example app here: https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-app

Comment: Thanks for your information. But I think my need is a little different. For example in the input field, I can submit the whole content to the server to get the result, which is similar with the use of auto complete. But what I want is when I press @te, the ajax will send the te as the search term. and it won't send other term.  At the same time, I can @ @ @ several times.

Comment: Got it. In that case you should be able to make something out of these two jsfiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/BfAtM/2/ & http://jsfiddle.net/Vmes9/6/