# Wrong number of arguments -trying to implement an autocomplete with jQueryui

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to implement an auto-complete form following this example [How to set up jquery ui autocomplete in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188157/how-to-set-up-jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-rails)

When I go to http://localhost:3000/initiatives/10.json?term=Ion I get a "Wrong number of arguments 1 for 0".

In my initiatives#show I have the following code:

```
if params[:term]
  Error points to this line - @people = User.all(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "#{params[:term]}%"])
else
  @people = User.all
end

respond_to do |format|  
  format.html  
  format.json { render :json => @people.to_json }
end
```

I am using PostgreSQL and I'm thinking the query is not made for this database.

This is the script for auto complete:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

    $('#delegatee').autocomplete({  
            minLength: 2,
            source: '<%= json_path %>',

            focus: function(event, ui) {
                console.log("xxxxxx");
                console.log(ui);

                $('#delegatee').val(ui.item.name);
                return false;
            },

            select: function(event, ui) {

                $('#delegatee').val(ui.item.name); 
        $('#delegatee_id').val(ui.item.id);
                return false;
            }
        })
        .data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )      
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )

                .append( "<a>" + item.name + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };
    });

</script>
```

"<%= json_path %> " leads to /initiatives/:id.json which renders the data.. correctly I think.

When I try the form out it gives me a 500 Internal Server error in the console, which I believe is the one I described above and it points me to this line in the jquery script: `xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );`

I'm using Rails 4.2.0.beta4 and Ruby 2.0.0p195.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails > 4.0, [ActiveRecord's `.all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/all) don't take multiple parameters as you are passing, and thus the `Wrong number of arguments 1 for 0` error.

The query you are trying to setup would be just:

```
@people = User.where('name LIKE ?', "#{params[:term]}%")
```

Hope it helps!