# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=json)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on the autocomplete feature in my Rails app and following the answer from [How to set-up jquery-ui autocomplete in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188157/how-to-set-up-jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-rails). When I type something into `input`, this error shows up: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=json)`? (`:term` is still equal to whatever I type) Why is there `id=json`?

```
<div>
  <input id="select_user" />
  <input id="link_user_id" name="link[user_id]" type="hidden"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#select_user').autocomplete({
      minLength: 1,
      source: '<%= user_path(:json) %>',
    })
    .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.user.name + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
  });
</script>
```

**User controller:**

```
def index
  if params[:term]
    @users = User.find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:term]}%"])
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @users.to_json }
  end
end
```

Comment: what version of rails are you using? User.find(:all) is not supported in newer version of rails try `User.where()`

Comment: @Vbp, it's 5.0.1

Comment: try something like this `User.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")`

Comment: just tried, but getting the same error `Couldn't find User with 'id'=json`. I was wondering if it has to do with this line 'source: '<%= user_path(:json) %>'`

Comment: that looks like a different error its saying couldn't find Font instead of User ?

Comment: try adding `byebug` in index action and check the value of params[:term] in console.. you should also be able to see the stack trace and the query that rails is sending to database in console

Comment: @Vbp, ahh sorry, should be `User`

Comment: `params[:term]` is populated by whatever i type in `input`, I'm just confused about why it's complaining about `id`. I don't seem to pass any `id` back to controller

Comment: the first argument to `find()` is `id` so it seems like its trying to use the `find()` method? Did you changed it to `where()` as I suggested above? may be try restarting server

Comment: @Vbp, yeah, im using `.where` but getting the same error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=json)`

Comment: can you add stack trace from console? I am not sure where is `find()` getting called from even after replacing that call with `where()` which shouldn't raise any exception as it just returns empty array if no matching records are found

Answer (score 4):

You issue is here:

```
source: '<%= user_path(:json) %>'
```

The first attribute that is passed into these url helpers is always the `object` or the `id`. So your issue is way before everything that was mentioned in the comments.

`user_path({}, format: :json)` would it be for adding format. This snipped will prob return `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=nil)`. So you have to find a way of passing id in.

I guess you want all to have all users returned that match in you `index` action. For this you have to use `users_path(format: :json)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try newer syntax

```
User.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
```

I think the syntax you are using is deprecated in rails 3