# jquery UI Combobox ONCHANGE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

how can I attach an onchange function in a jqueryUI combobox? Here is my code:

```
$(".cmbBox").combobox({
     change:function(){
         alert($(this).val());
     }
});
```

When the value changes, it will alert the updated value.

Any help please.. :)

Comment: Which combobox? Kindly provide the URL for the specific one you are using.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox this one.. the combobox submenu sir..

Comment: In fact, there's already a "hook" for the onchange event. Look for autocompletechange. That's what I used and it works fine! I added a answer that match with this comment

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The combobox example source is all right there in the example.  I'd trigger the `change` event of the underlying select by modifying the source code like this (changing the `select` event handler inside autocomplete initialization inside the plugin):

```
/* Snip */
select: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.item.option.selected = true;
    self._trigger( "selected", event, {
        item: ui.item.option
    });
    select.trigger("change");                            
},
/* Snip */
```

and then define an event handler for the regular `change` event of the `select`:

```
$(".cmbBox").change(function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Unfortunately this won't work exactly the same way as the normal `select.change` event: it will trigger even you select the same item from the combobox.

Try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/hAM9H/

Comment: Very nice! That is exactly what I was thinking, though I got confused by the line above "._trigger", I thought this was the way to trigger events.

Is "trigger" an javascript or jQuery Method? 

Thanks

Comment: @ClayBoom: Good question-- `self._trigger` is an internal jqueryUI function (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js#L348) that autocomplete uses.

Comment: Thanks! I was just wondering the difference between `_trigger` and `trigger` because both are used in this context.

Comment: I had to replace "self" with "that" so that this snippet would work. and even then, it only catched changes that were the result of selecting from the drop-down list but not from the free-text. eventually I only added to the "change:" function below the "select:" in combobox.js this>>>select.trigger("change");<<<  and now it catches all sort of changes.

Comment: +1 for the jsfiddle link.  The jeasyui.com site is a start, but there aren't anywhere near enough examples on there.  I can't find a single one that doesn't use 'easyui-combobox' for the creation...

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, this code no longer works with the most recent version of the combobox code. I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: select is not defined` when I try to use this.

Comment: @Nate I'm not sure what's happening on your code, but check out the last comments on this answer, might be the case http://stackoverflow.com/a/11042693/1067465

Answer (score 25):

IMHO, an even simpler way to detect the user has changed the combobox (without having to tweak the jQuery UI autocomplete combobox source code) is as follows; this works for me.  It's repetitious if you've got lots of them, though surely there's a way to refactor.  Thanks to all who have studied and explained this widget at length, here and elsewhere.

```
$("#theComboBox").combobox({ 
        select: function (event, ui) { 
            alert("the select event has fired!"); 
        } 
    }
);
```

Comment: This was what I needed.  The other method talking about triggers and editing the code didn't work because the source I had was different enough that I couldn't find the right place to add it.  But this technique worked great!  Thanks.

Comment: David code is great and it worked for me. Thanks David. Andrew code look pretty decent but I am not sure why it did not work for me.

Comment: Not working for me : 

`$("#productList").combobox({    
  url: 'productList',
  valueField:'code',
     textField:'code', 
     editable:false,
            select: function (event, ui) { 
               alert("the select event has fired!"); 
           } 
 });`

Answer (score 1):

Into the ui.combobox plugin :

i added at the end of the select method :

```
$(input).trigger("change", ui);
```

i added before the "var input ..." :

```
select.attr('inputId', select.attr('id') + '_input');
```

after, to have a functional onchange event... on ui.combobox i commented the change method and moved its code to the checkval method that extends ui.autocomplete :

```
$.extend( $.ui.autocomplete, {
    checkVal: function (select) {
            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                        valid = false;
            $(select).children("option").each(function () {
                if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                    this.selected = valid = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (!valid) {
                // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                $(this).val("");
                $(select).val("");
                $(this).data("autocomplete").term = "";
                $(this).data("autocomplete").close();
            }
        }
});
```

and i coded the input change method as below :

```
var oCbo = ('#MyCbo').combobox();
$('#' + oCbo.attr('inputId')).change(function () {

    // from select event : check if value exists
    if (arguments.length < 2) {
        $.ui.autocomplete.checkVal.apply(this, [oCbo]);
    }

        // YOUR CODE HERE
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#theComboBox").combobox({ 
    select: function (event, ui) { 
        alert("the select event has fired!"); 
    } 
}
```

);

Comment: This is exactly the same code as suggested by David Barrows 5 months previously.

Answer (score 0):

It says in the "Events" section of the documentation, that you [handle a change](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-change) like this...

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   change: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me

```
if('function' == typeof(callback = ui.item.option.parentElement.onchange))
                        callback.apply(this, []);
```

just before

```
self._trigger("selected", event, {
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest way (IMHO), if you are deploying combobox as widget:

1. find "_create" method in widget
2. inside of it look for "autocomplete" (where input is managed)
3. add (use) "select" method to get your data: ui.item.value

```
(function($){
$.widget( "ui.combobox", {
    // default options
    options: {
    //your options ....
    },
    _create: function() {

    //some code ....

    //this is input you look for
    input = $( "" )
    .appendTo( wrapper )
    .val( value )
    .addClass( "ui-state-default" )

    //this is autocomplete you look for
    .autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
        //some code ...
        },

        //this is select method you look for ...
        select: function( event, ui ) {

        //this is your selected value
        console.log(ui.item.value);
        },
        change: function( event, ui ) {

        //some code ...
        }
    })
    //rest of code
    },

    destroy: function() {
    this.wrapper.remove();
    this.element.show();
    $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there's already a "hook" for the onchange event.

Just change the following line for the method call or the callback that you want:

```
autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
```

Comment: Can you give an example where you change the above so it will trigger an alert? or a function that triggers an alert?