# jquery ui autocomplete autofocus with category element as first

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to get my first item in my jquery autocomplete selected when using categories. Now my menu looks something like this:

```
[category] <- autofocus selects this one
[item1]    <- autofocus should select this one
[item2]
[item3]
[category]
[item4]
[item5]
etc.
```

What i already tried:
1. adding ui-state-disabled to my category 
2. searched google how to overwrite the menu.next() function so i could detect if the item is a category
3. searched google on how to set the selected element manually including triggering the select event

So far no luck for me so i hope you guys have any suggestions ^^

fidle: http://jsfiddle.net/uynct53p/5/  (works with jquery 1.9 but not with 1.11)

Comment: Can you upload some code? Or a jsfiddle?

Comment: You can trigger a `select` event with the field wanted on `open`. This won't disable improperly formatted items, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633727/how-do-you-trigger-autocomplete-select-event-manually-in-jqueryui

Comment: added jsfidle to show the problem, as you can see the categories are selectable and also get selected by autoFocus in jquery 1.11. if i use jquery 1.9 it works like i want to, categories are not selectable and autofocus = selects the first real item

Answer (score 0):

Since it's still an input element, you can invoke `val` method on the autocomplete in order to set its value.

Since you want to set the value to the first element in your `data` object, simply do

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({ /* ... */ })
.val(data[0].label)
// ...
```

Your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uynct53p/7/

Comment: that would be true if the fidle was a real representation of my problem.
the problem at this moment is that with jquery 1.11 categories = are selectable, while in jquery 1.10 they are not...

Answer (score 0):

Found: [jquery ui autocomplete combobox with categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039814/jquery-ui-autocomplete-combobox-with-categories)

answered by: Aureltime

this makes categories non selectable in jquery 1.11.*

```
$.extend($.ui.menu.prototype.options, {
    items: "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)"
});
```