# Dropdown onchange function call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

In my page I used a drop down. When change the dropdown values it will call the function named sample. But onchange function is not working. Anyone can help me to solve this issue.

```
<!doctype html>    
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Combobox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <style>
    .ui-combobox {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .ui-combobox-toggle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin-left: -1px;
        padding: 0;
        /* support: IE7 */
        *height: 1.7em;
        *top: 0.1em;
    }
    .ui-combobox-input {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0.3em;
    }
    </style>
```

**JS file**

```
    <script>
    (function( $ ) {
        $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
            _create: function() {
                var input,
                    that = this,
                    wasOpen = false,
                    select = this.element.hide(),
                    selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
                    value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "",
                    wrapper = this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
                        .addClass( "ui-combobox" )
                        .insertAfter( select );

                function removeIfInvalid( element ) {
                    var value = $( element ).val(),
                        matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( value ) + "$", "i" ),
                        valid = false;
                    select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                        if ( $( this ).text().match( matcher ) ) {
                            this.selected = valid = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    if ( !valid ) {
                        // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                        $( element )
                            .val( "" )
                            .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
                            .tooltip( "open" );
                        select.val( "" );
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
                        }, 2500 );
                        input.data( "ui-autocomplete" ).term = "";
                    }
                }

                input = $( "<input>" )
                    .appendTo( wrapper )
                    .val( value )
                    .attr( "title", "" )
                    .addClass( "ui-state-default ui-combobox-input" )
                    .autocomplete({
                        delay: 0,
                        minLength: 0,
                        source: function( request, response ) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                            response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                                var text = $( this ).text();
                                if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                                    return {
                                        label: text.replace(
                                            new RegExp(
                                                "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                                $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                                ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                            ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                                        value: text,
                                        option: this
                                    };
                            }) );
                        },
                        select: function( event, ui ) {
                            ui.item.option.selected = true;
                            that._trigger( "selected", event, {
                                item: ui.item.option
                            });
                        },
                        change: function( event, ui ) {
                            if ( !ui.item ) {
                                removeIfInvalid( this );
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );

                input.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                    return $( "<li>" )
                        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                        .appendTo( ul );
                };

                $( "<a>" )
                    .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                    .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
                    .tooltip()
                    .appendTo( wrapper )
                    .button({
                        icons: {
                            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                        },
                        text: false
                    })
                    .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
                    .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle" )
                    .mousedown(function() {
                        wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
                    })
                    .click(function() {
                        input.focus();

                        // close if already visible
                        if ( wasOpen ) {
                            return;
                        }

                        // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                        input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                    });

                input.tooltip({
                    tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
                });
            },

            _destroy: function() {
                this.wrapper.remove();
                this.element.show();
            }
        });
    })( jQuery );

    $(function() {
        $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
        $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
            $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
        });
    });
function sample()
{
alert("testing");
}     
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

**HTML coding**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
    <select id="combobox" onchange="sample();">
        <option value="">Select one...</option>
        <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
        <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
        <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
        <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="C++">C++</option>
        <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
        <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
        <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
        <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
        <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
        <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
        <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
        <option value="Java">Java</option>
        <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
        <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
        <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
        <option value="Python">Python</option>
        <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
        <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
        <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button id="toggle">Show underlying select</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the name of js file which you have write in question ?

Comment: I take that coding from this URL just used for autocomplete functionality http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html

Comment: No need to write script tag in js file but in your js file you have write script tag as well as html code. Why ?

Comment: That is not separate js file that is within the coding. To identify separtely, I used the title as js file. Dont get confused

Comment: Default onchange event of the selectbox will not work as it gets converted by jquery UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default onchange event of the selectbox will not work as it gets converted by jquery UI.

Use jQuery UI built in event for the same:

```
$( "#combobox" ).autocomplete({
change: function( event, ui ) { alert("testing");}
});
```

**Ref:** http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change

**----EDIT----**

Solution is here :
Possible duplicate of : [jquery UI Combobox ONCHANGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760285/jquery-ui-combobox-onchange)

Comment: at the end of the anonymous function that makes the combobox to a combobox

Comment: after this line: $( "#toggle" ).click(function() { $( "#combobox" ).toggle();});

Answer (score 0):

This is because jqueryUI (or your code?!) hides the original combobox, replacing it with its own.

Use firebug or similar to insprect the combobox. It is hidden!

You can use a js-eventlistener to fix it, like you did it here:

```
$( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
 $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
});
```

However,

```
$(".ui-combobox input").change(function(){
    sample();
});
```

this does not work, because change is not triggered by a selection.
Only by manual input.
So you will have to trigge it:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {

                $(this).trigger("change"); // here
                            ui.item.option.selected = true;
                            that._trigger( "selected", event, {
                                item: ui.item.option
                            });
                        },
```

Comment: Any example coding for that eventlistener handling