# Unable to focus on jquery select widget dynamic input field

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-widgets

Basically I'm extending this question [jQuery Combobox/select autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082441/jquery-combobox-select-autocomplete)
Here, I have updated the [fiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/thinkfreedom/YCTDQ/312/). The problem is that, if I met certain condition from the first menu(if the mainmenu selection value is two), I want to set focus in the input field in the the submenu.
Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<select id="mainmenu" style="width:300px">
    <option value>Select from menu</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="submenu" style="width:300px">
    <option value>Select from submenu</option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
    $('select').combobox();
});

$( document ).ready(function() {

    console.log("console logging.");
    $('#mainmenu').change(function() {
            var selectVal = $('#mainmenu :selected').val();
            console.log("selected: " + selectVal);
            if(selectVal == 'two'){
                console.log("value: "+selectVal);
                //$('#submenu ~ input:first').autocomplete("search", "");
                $('#submenu ~ input:first').focus();
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: If you're already using jQuery-UI, why not use the `selectmenu` widget? It's cleaner, doesn't require any extra code and will eliminate this issue for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `onchange` event of `combobox` like this `$("#mainmenu").combobox({...` and then set `focus` using `$('#submenu').next().find('input').focus();`

Here's complete code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#mainmenu").combobox({
        selected: function (event, ui) {
           var selectVal = $('#mainmenu :selected').val();
            if(selectVal=='two'){
             $('#submenu').next().find('input').focus();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YCTDQ/315/)**

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery-UI's [selectmenu widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu):

HTML

```
<select id="mainmenu" style="width:300px">
    <option value>Select from menu</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="submenu" style="width:300px">
    <option value>Select from submenu</option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $('#mainmenu, #submenu').selectmenu();
    $('#mainmenu').selectmenu({
        'change': function (e, ui) {
            var selectVal = $('option:selected', this).val();
            if (selectVal == 'two') {
                $('#submenu').selectmenu('open');
                $('#submenu option:eq(1)').focus();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/YCTDQ/314/) for proof